# Бэкграунд с наклоном крайней части

Tags: android, интерфейс, background-task

Ребята подскажите как реализовать наклон как нарисовал на картинке. Хочу сделать такой блок, не часть тулбара.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что за  бэкграунд с наклоном крайней части. Это оранжевый "обрубок" под тулбаром?

Comment: да, именно он))

Comment: Теперь понятно=)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Вообщем, берете вырезаете этот кусок, сохраняете его в png. В xml добавляете вьюшку с этим бэкграундом типа:

```
<View android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/background"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"/>
```

Соответственно я это расписал, учитывая что ваш toolbar и view лежат в `RelativeLayout`. Ежели вы собираетесь туда засовывать элементы управления, то используйте уже классы разметки, которые вам удобней, вместо `View`

Comment: а без png можно сделать(об это думал)? в drawable xml?

пс. спасибо)

Comment: ну как вырежете этот рисунок, то поместите его в папку drawable=) Без этого никак. Незачто

Comment: это понятно) я имел ввиду задать background цветом, и сам наклон сделать через код xml без использования png)))

Comment: А, незнаю, думаю врядли=)

Comment: а то захотелось мне именно так)) спасибо)